# Sorting a list containing NaNs

Tags: list, sorting, floating-point, nan

If I have a list of floating point numbers containing: Infinity, -Infinity, Other random decimal number and one NaN. Where should the NaN be after the list has been sorted?? I'm using bubble sort if that helps

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: There is no problem to solve, its a question and in asking for the answer

Comment: What language? There is an easy answer for Java.

Answer (score 5):

In order to sort you need a consistent order, which means, for example, making an ordering rule for NaN.

Fortunately, the work has already been done in Java. `java.lang.Double` is `Comparable`, and its `compareTo` uses extended rules including "Double.NaN is considered by this method to be equal to itself and greater than all other double values (including Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)."

It also has a [compare](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double-) method that compares two double primitives using those extended rules, rather than the `<=` etc. rules.

If you are programming in Java you can use this directly in your sort. If you are using `float` rather than `double`, see the corresponding method in `java.lang.Float`. If you are programming in another language, you can still read and copy the rules from Java, and use them in your comparison function.

If you use this in your sort you should expect `NaN` to be at the very end of the sorted list, after all finite values and positive infinity.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I wasn't aware of that. I found the documentation for `compareTo` at this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

Answer (score 3):

You **cannot** sort a list of floating-point values including NaN using `<=` as comparison because `<=` is not an order on floating-point values including `NaN`: it is not reflexive (`NaN <= NaN` would have to hold for `<=` to be reflexive. It doesn't).

You are breaking the pre-requisites of the sorting algorithm. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

The NaN would be put at the beginning or the end of the sorted array depending on the implementation of Bubble Sort in question.

It depends entirely on how you define your ordering criterion.